# How can I get more out of `$post` in an `add_action` callback?

Tags: actions

I have the following action callback set up:

```
function abc_save_post($post_id, $post)
{
    // do stuff

    echo '<pre>'.print_r($post,true).'</pre>';
}
add_action('save_post', 'abc_save_post', 10, 2);
```

The thing is that `$post` is a very trimmed down version of `$_POST` and is missing lots of data that I want to get at. How can I get more data into `$post`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the post ID, provided by `$post_id` (and stored at `$post->ID`) to use the various functions WordPress provides to get any extra data related to that post (`get_the_terms`,`get_post_meta` etc).

Performance wise you suffer no loss by using these functions as opposed to trying to force more data into the `$post` object (probably the reverse in fact), since WordPress caches data related to posts (such as taxonomy terms, post meta,...)